# PostgreSQL: Access enclosing function's argument inside DO block

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, scope, plpgsql

I have an SQL function which has a DO block, and when trying to access an argument of the enclosing function inside the DO block I get a " column does not exist" error. What am I missing?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1(a1 TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS $$
DO $DO$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'a1 = %', a1;
END
$DO$;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL VOLATILE;

SELECT f1('AA');
```

> ERROR: column "a1" does not exist
>   SQL state: 42703
>   Context: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 3 at RAISE
>   SQL function "f1" statement 1

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If you want to use PL/pgSQL, then why don't you simply make that function a PL/pgSQL function?

Comment: My actual function already contains some significant SQL code, I'd rather not drop and re-create it as plpgsql.

Comment: A SQL function can only contain a single SQL statement, so there is not much work involved to turn that into a PL/pgSQL function. You simply add a `begin ...end`, put a `return query` in front of the `select` and change `language sql` to  language `plpgsql`. You apparently **need** PL/pgSQL otherwise you wouldn't have the `DO` block.

Comment: The original function does contain several SQL statements. I'm aware of the fact that only the last one can return values.
Anyway, I did drop the function and create is as PLPGSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You has wrong language specification

```
$$ LANGUAGE SQL VOLATILE;
```

should be:

```
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

The `DO` statement is new, and there is plpgsql language by default.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to have a possibility to raise a notice in an SQL function. The DO block however is not a good idea, because the function's arguments are not visible inside it. Instead, you can prepare an auxiliary function that raises a notice:

```
create or replace function raise_notice(anyelement)
returns void language plpgsql as $$
begin
    raise notice '%', $1;
end $$;
```

Now you can use it in an SQL function, e.g.:

```
create or replace function f1(a1 text)
returns text language sql as $$
    select raise_notice(a1);
    select a1;
$$;

select f1('some text');

NOTICE:  some text
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function raise_notice(anyelement) line 3 at RAISE
SQL function "f1" statement 1
    f1     
-----------
 some text
(1 row)
```

Comment: Actaully no... My original intention was to keep as much as possible in a pure SQL function, and only put plpgsql in a DO block, but seems like this mixing doesn't work, so I've changed the whole function to plpgsql.